# How to pass kinectV2 data streams by connecting multiple servers to single client computer using c++.Each server is connected to kinect sensor

Tags: networking, tcp, kinect, gstreamer

I have 3 machines which are connected to  kinect sensorV2 and i need kinect data from all the three machines and it will be passed to my client computer.How can i achieve this in C++

Thanks,
kiruba

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [kv2Streamer](https://github.com/Samsung/kv2streamer). It streams Kinect v2 data from one computer to another using gstreamer (I think). By default, kv2Streamer is most likely not capable of streaming from multiple clients, but you might be able to adapt it to your needs. For more details see [kv2Stramer issue #6](https://github.com/Samsung/kv2streamer/issues/6).

But beware, streaming all the data from one Kinect @ 30 fps uncompressed is more than a gigabit LAN can handle. Even when using compression, data from 3 Kinects will be quite a lot.

Comment: Yes,i look at kv2streamer,it sends kinect data from one computer to another using multicast ip.So what multicast does is,running Kv2server from kv2streamer application in one computer and receives the kinect data from the server to multiple clients.so i will run the kv2server like this kv2server 224.0.0.252 kv2sensor2.Here 224.0.0.252 is multicast address.Hence if i run multiple servers and request the same 224.0.0.252 from different clients then how it will differentiate between the multiple servers.

Comment: Can't you run the servers on different multicast addresses? Or use different ports?

Comment: I saw your your issue over at the kv2Streamer github and added a link to my answer, in case anybody else is interested.