# Streaming Kinect data over WiFI

Tags: video, stream, wifi, kinect

I wish to Stream Kinect RGB Video from a PC to which Kinect is connected via USB to another PC (or an Android device) which is on the same WiFi network. I presently have no clue about how to do it?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not a question for stack overflow. Ask Super User or arqade.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32325973/how-to-pass-kinectv2-data-streams-by-connecting-multiple-servers-to-single-clien might help

Answer (score 0):

you can watch this project for streaming with Kinect:

https://github.com/Kinect/RoomAliveToolkit/tree/master/ProCamCalibration/KinectServer